# retrieve an openstack container objects list with python (or any other easy way)

Tags: python, openstack

I'm trying to retrieve the list of a container content, using python and openstack lib.

after a succesful connection with :

```
conn = connection.Connection(
    ...)
```

and a succesful response to :

```
for cont in conn.object_store.containers():
     print(cont.name)
```

I'd like to retrieve the objects list of one of the containers. I find this one, but it doesn't work :

```
for data in conn.get_container('container_name')[1]:
    print ('{0}\t{1}\t{2}'.format(data['name'], data['bytes'], data['last_modified']))
```

Any better approach to advise ?
Thanks
Méric.

Comment: This looks like you use the OpenStack SDK. I don't know where the get_container() comes from (which could simply mean that I am ignorant). To list objects in a container, see https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/guides/object_store.html#listing-objects.

Comment: What version of the OpenStack SDK are you using? It seems that the `get_container` method returns a dictionary. The `[1]` operation can not be used on a dictionary.